# How can I prevent overlaying divs from producing a gap at certain resolutions? (google zeitgeist)

Tags: html, css

Here is my website: http://designobvio.us/portfolio/body.html

Here's my aspiring website: http://www.googlezeitgeist.com/en/top-searches/battlefield_three

I'm getting pretty close to the layout; however, when you shrink the browser vertically too much it produces a gap.

Also I cant even debug resolutions great then mine(1280x800) which I'm sure something else breaks in the other direction.

*Update:  could it be the general size of the photo?  Zeitgeist uses 800x800 (sq) image; while i use a rectangle?*

The problem could also be an error in the structure of my HTML? (this is a really tough layout for me)

```
<section class="bodySection">
  <div id="body-wrapper-left" class="class="">
    <div id="me"></div>
    <div id="pattern"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="body-wrapper-right"> </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
<!--end of bodySection-->
```

or my CSS:

```
html, body, #body-wrapper, .bodySection {
    height: 100%;
}
#body-wrapper-left {
    position: relative;
    width:35%;
    height: 100%;
}
#body-wrapper-left #me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://designobvio.us/portfolio/img/Me.jpg') repeat-y;
    z-index: 1;
    -o-background-size:auto 100%;
    -webkit-background-size:auto 100%;
    -moz-background-size:auto 100%;
    background-size:auto 100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
}
#body-wrapper-left #pattern {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://designobvio.us/portfolio/img/sliderBG.png') repeat;
    z-index: 2;
}
#body-wrapper-right {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    min-width:65%;
    width:65%;
    background:#fff;
    z-index:9;
}
```

To my knowledge it looks like its a set min-height // min-width (perhaps a max in the other direction) value somewhere.  Anyone know where and what to select so I can unify widths and heights so the effect is more like Google Zeitgeist?

Comment: Where is the gap produced? I can't picture it.

Comment: heres a screen shot http://www.designobvio.us/Gap.jpg as you can see i shrunk the screen more vertical then horizontal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use CSS3's background cover option.

```
#element {
background: url(http://designobvio.us/portfolio/img/Me.jpg) center center;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/B7W2K/20/

Though obviously this won't work in older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

The gap you are seeing is due to the fact that your image is trying to scale vertically instead of horizontally. You can fix this gap by flipping that behavior like so:

```
#body-wrapper-left #me {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: url('http://designobvio.us/portfolio/img/Me.jpg') repeat-y;
    z-index: 1;
    -o-background-size:100% auto; /* notice the flip in the statement */
    -webkit-background-size:100% auto;
    -moz-background-size:100% auto;
    background-size:100% auto;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
    transition: all 0.20s ease-out;
}
```

Comment: now it doesnt resize the picture correctly.  if i made the picture a square and then resized by vertical would this fix the problem?

Comment: Came in a bit late, saw that somebody else beat me to the second option, `background-size:cover`, good luck :)